# how do I stream content from amazon in android?

Tags: android, audio-streaming, amazon-appstore

I am creating an app that streams music from a movie soundtrack, and prompts the user to guess what movie it is from. Do to some legal ramifications of using third party music, I am forced to think of another way to do it, than using my own streaming service. one thing that I have come up with, is using amazon's music service (being that with them, it will allow you to stream up to 30 seconds of music without buying it.) how would I be able to stream music from their site in android? is there an amazon API that I can use? how would I access their server to stream it? and do they allow people to stream from them, or do I have to get special permission?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bet this is against their terms of service and you will likely be shut down pretty quickly.